# Automate Mouse Click

Tags: windows, scripting

I was just wondering which language/script should I use to automate some mouse clicks. I have to keep selecting the next check box until there are no more. I tried looking and found python gui but it looks like it takes the screen resolution into account. 
Any help as to where I could start looking would be greatly appreciated. (for windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the problem before of ticking lots of checkboxes (into the hundreds). I found that, when the checkbox was in focus, pressing space toggled it (test this with your application). Changing the focus was possible with the arrow keys, or tab.

I then used powershell to automate this (basically I created a macro), but the point is: Try if you can get the workflow to work with keyboard commands, that will be a lot easier to automate than mouse clicks. Once you have an idea how to solve this problem with the keyboard, you can look for tools to automate that (if you already used python, there are probably python libraries for that).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a `macro recorder`, but screen resolution would complicate that).

If you want to script it yourself, then you simply cannot beat [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

There is a Python wrapper at https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/, if you prefer to code in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) regularly for this.  Very reliable, though I find the source syntax a bit baffling sometimes.  For something very complex, I would probably call AutoHotKey from Python or Powershell in some fashion.